# VS 2017: Property value is not valid. - Enabling SSL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl

I am trying to enable SSL in my VS project. However, every time I switch the property value from False to True I get the following dialog box error:
"`Property value is not valid.`"

Based on the "Details" I thought it was a permissions issues, I navigated to the file path shown and I unchecked "Read-Only" checked back and the problem still exists. Also this applies to any other property I try to modify in the project solution.

VS Version: 15.6.0 Preview 7.0

[image]

Comment: OneDrive? You are working from OneDrive? That's weird. Three things to try: 1)use a non-preview VS version, 2) use a local folder and 3) delete the `.vs` folder after closing VS

Comment: Well Sir, you are correct moving the project folder from OneDrive to my local C: Drive fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As Camilo Terevinto stated...I moved the project folder out of OneDrive onto my local C: Drive and that fixed the issue right away. Thank you.